# What does “get out there” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> If Hong Bo wants his new product to be successful worldwide, he must
>   get out there and really peddle it.

What does “get out there” mean in this context?

Comment: Go out into the real world. Leave the comforts and assurances of his home and get in front of people. Take risk. Be proactive.

Comment: "There" is the worldwide marketplace.  He needs to increase his activity and visibility in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a figure of speech it means something close to "make an effort", similar to the colloquial "give it all you've got" or "get into it".

In this specific context it has this meaning as well as the more direct one - Hong Bo must physically get out "there" - the real world - and make the effort to market his product, as Dan says in his comment.

Comment: or "start doing stuff"

Comment: I happened to see your answer. May I ask what does `as a figure of speech` mean?

Answer (score 0):

To me "get out there" means to put yourself in the public, be adventurous, get out of your comfort zone, try new things, and be a litte crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Go, get going! Be brave, good courage, and initiative take those steps to be a part of the whole. It's all part of learning, "get out there" we can learn from both positive and negative experiences.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this idiom originated in the sports world, where players are sent out from the locker room and onto the playing field by the coach who tells them to give their very best effort.

> Now get out there, and give it your best!

The underlying context that makes it applicable to the business world is  the notion that there will be *stiff competition* that cannot be overcome by halfhearted effort.